# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'restaurantToDelete' referenced before assignment Flask app

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

When I try to delete an item from the database in a Flask view, the following error is shown

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'restaurantToDelete' referenced before assignment
```

```
@app.route('/restaurant/<int:restaurant_id>/delete',methods=['GET','POST'])
def deleteRestaurant(restaurant_id):
    if request.method=='POST':
        restaurantToDelete=session.query(Restaurant).filter_by(id=restaurant_id).one()
        session.delete(restaurantToDelete)
        session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('showRestaurants'))
    else:
        return render_template('deleterestaurant.html',restaurant=restaurantToDelete)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the else, at that point restaurantToDelete isn't defined, your code should be something like

```
@app.route('/restaurant/<int:restaurant_id>/delete',methods=['GET','POST'])
def deleteRestaurant(restaurant_id):
    restaurantToDelete=session.query(Restaurant).filter_by(id=restaurant_id).one()

    if request.method=='POST':
        session.delete(restaurantToDelete)
        session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('showRestaurants'))
    else:
        return render_template('deleterestaurant.html',restaurant=restaurantToDelete)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're defining the variable `restaurantToDelete` inside an `if`-block, and then you try to use it inside the `else`-block. If the `request.method` is not `POST`, the variable does not exist, because your code does not enter the `if`-block. You can fix this by fetching the restaurant before checking for the request type:

```
@app.route('/restaurant/<int:restaurant_id>/delete',methods=['GET','POST'])
def deleteRestaurant(restaurant_id):
    restaurantToDelete=session.query(Restaurant).filter_by(id=restaurant_id).one()
    if request.method=='POST':
        session.delete(restaurantToDelete)
        session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('showRestaurants'))
    else:
        return render_template('deleterestaurant.html',restaurant=restaurantToDelete)
```