# Flask Pagination : UnboundLocalError: local variable 'res' referenced before assignment error

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, jinja2

I'm working on the flask pagination, when i try to achieve it, i get the UnboundLocalError, if i try to remove all the variables, still the pagination doesn't work.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) 
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/fetchrecords",methods=["POST","GET"])
def fetchrecords():
    per_page = 10
    page = request.args.get(get_page_parameter(), type=int, default=1)
    offset = (page - 1) * per_page
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    if request.method == 'POST':
         query = request.form['query']
         cur.execute("SELECT * FROM emp ORDER BY pid")
         res = cur.fetchall()
         for i in res:
             total +=float(i['salary'])
         numrows = int(cur.rowcount)             
         cur.execute("SELECT * FROM emp ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT %s, %s", (per_page, offset))
         res = cur.fetchall()
         if query == '':
             cur.execute("SELECT * FROM emp ORDER BY pid")
             total = cur.fetchall() 
             numrows = int(cur.rowcount)      
             cur.execute("SELECT * FROM emp ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT %s, %s", (per_page, offset))
             res = cur.fetchall()     
             pagination = Pagination(page=page, per_page=per_page, offset=offset, total=len(total))                                           
        else:
              search_text = request.form['query']
              cur.execute("SELECT * from emp WHERE name LIKE '%{}%' OR title LIKE '%{}%' OR pid LIKE '%{}%' ORDER BY pid".format(search_text,search_text,search_text))
              res = cur.fetchall() 
              for i in res: 
                  total +=float(i['salary'])
              numrows = int(cur.rowcount) 
              pagination = Pagination(page=page, per_page=per_page, offset=offset, total=len(total), record_name='res')
  elif request.method == 'GET':
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM emp ORDER BY pid")
        total = cur.fetchall()
        per_page = 25 
        page = request.args.get(get_page_parameter(), type=int, default=1)      
        offset = (page - 1) * per_page
        pagination = Pagination(page=page, per_page=per_page,total=len(total), 
              css_framework='bootstrap4')   
        numrows = int(cur.rowcount)
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM portal ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT %s, %s", (per_page, offset))
        res = cur.fetchall()    
             
  return jsonify({'htmlresponse': render_template('response.html', res=res, numrows=numrows, total=total,pagination=pagination)})
```

resonse.html

```
<h4>Total : {{numrows}} </h4></tr>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          ..Table header.. 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    {% for row in res %}  
    <tr>  Data base values here...</tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{{pagination.links}}
```

Can anyone please help me, how to work with pagination and whats wrong I'm doing. This would be very helpful thanks in advance

Comment: Might [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890182/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-restauranttodelete-referenced-before-assignm?rq=1) help you out? Basically, you want to find a way to define `res` even when you receive a `GET` request. One way you could do this would be to insert another `if` statement to catch any `GET` requests.

Comment: i also tried to put the variable outside of if condition but in the second pages i get the data in bytes not as table. Can you help me how to solve this problem

Comment: i mean to say the pagination, page 1,page 2 and so on.. i also have search button this won't be exceuted. it executes only in post method

Comment: `elif request.method == 'GET':
     cur.execute("SELECT * FROM emp ORDER BY pid")
     total = cur.fetchall()
     per_page = 25
     page = request.args.get(get_page_parameter(), type=int, default=1)
     offset = (page - 1) * per_page
     pagination = Pagination(page=page, per_page=per_page, total=len(total), css_framework='bootstrap4')
     numrows = int(cur.rowcount)
      cur.execute("SELECT * FROM portal ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT %s, %s", (per_page, offset))
      res = cur.fetchall()     
   returnrender_template('index.html',res=res,pagination=pagination,numrows=numrows)`

Comment: @Patrick Yoder i tried the above code, but the search button doesn't work also the page 1 is empty and i will have data from second page. Really i'm understand how to do it

Comment: @Patrick Yoder No still this doesn't work.. Do you have any idea about how to solve it

Comment: Thanks that's helpful, but now that you have solved your initial problem of 'res' not being defined, maybe you should ask a new question with details on what your problem is? Your update tells me that the problem is likely with pagination, and I myself have not had experience with flask-pagination, so I'm afraid I can't help you much further.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when the endpoint is invoked via an **http get** request.
The creation of the `res` variable is enclosed within this if:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

while this `return` here (which refers to the variable `res`) is outside the if

```
return jsonify({'htmlresponse': render_template('response.html', res=res, numrows=numrows, total=total,pagination=pagination)})
```

Comment: Can you help me how to achieve it, because i want to pass all the variables to render into response.html

Comment: i also tried to put the variable outside of if condition but in the second pages i get the data in bytes not as table.